# find api code of soundcloud track

Tags: api, soundcloud

Is there a quick way to get the api url of a track or a playlist on soundcloud?

for example the api link for this playlist:

```
https://soundcloud.com/thump/sets/thump-x-avolta-5
```

is:

```
https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/playlists/40626677
```

---

and the api link for this track:

```
https://soundcloud.com/larryfisherman/the-star-room-og-version
```

is:

```
https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/154949628
```

---

### What I am trying to do:

This is the code I have for a vimeo link.

```
if($tvideo === "Vimeo"){
        $Vimeo = "html('<iframe src=\"//player.vimeo.com/video/" . $video . "?color=bc2122\" width=\"700\" height=\"525\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>');";
}
```

In a form I have `$tvideo` (the type of video).

And `$video` a code from the url for example in:

```
https://vimeo.com/83528019
```

the number:

```
83528019
```

---

I want to do the same with soundcloud but the embedding html is very strange† so instead of finding the number (as for the vimeo case) I need to find the api url.

†:

```
html('<iframe width=\"720\" height=\"500\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"no\" src=\"https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/150885898&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true\"></iframe>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Would http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#resolve help?

> $ curl -v 'http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=http://soundcloud.com/matas/hobnotropic&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
>
> < HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
>   < Location: http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/49931.json